Creating new azure web app with New-AzWebApp based on container image
My goal is to achieve something with powershell to automate the creation of an azure web app from powershell.
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName -Location 'West Europe' 
-AppServicePlan $ServicePlan -ContainerImageName "one/image:latest"

The cmdlet is working fine... but the application created this way has still this kind of stack (click below to see image, don't have permission yet).
stack is wrong
If i do it via the Azure Portal and create such web application with docker image.
The stack is (click below to see image, don't have permission yet):
stack is ok
I was able to fix the stack by running this cmdlet:
Set-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$WebAppName/config/web" 
-Properties @{"linuxFxVersion"="DOCKER|$dockerImage"} -Force

Then the UI is displaying correct information in the properties... but if I check the app logs data... it does not pull my docker image, it still pull another image (not the one I set up in the original new-azwebapp cmdlet).
If I check the web app I created manually, the logs shows the correct image is pulled for the web app.
How can i create such web app based on docker container without using the portal?
I am expepcting the cmdlet from MS PowerShell Azure Module to create a web app based on a docker image as if i do it from the Azure Portal itself.
Final conclusion :
The powershell cmdlet vs the cli cmdlet does not create the same azure web app. Does any of you already faces this ?
CLI cmd seems to create the web app correctly.
az webapp create --resource-group ResourceGroupName --plan WebAppPlan --name WebAppName --deployment-container-image-name one/image:latest

PowerShell cmdlet seems to create the web app not correctly.
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName  -Name WebAppName -AppServicePlan WebAppPlan -ContainerImageName "one/image:latest"


If you are creating a container based Web App on Azure App Service, it is important that you create it in the right App Service Plan. There are three types of App Service Plan:

Windows ASP
Windows Containers ASP
Linux ASP

For example, if you are trying to create a Windows Container Web App, use the following commands:
New-AzAppServicePlan -Name "PV3ASP" -Location "West US 2" -ResourceGroupName "Xenon" 
-Tier PremiumV3 -HyperV

New-AzWebApp -Name "xapp" -AppServicePlan "PV3ASP" -Location "West US 2" 
-ResourceGroupName "Xenon" -ContainerImageName 
"mcr.microsoft.com/azure-app-service/windows/parkingpage:latest" 
-ContainerRegistryUrl <optional> 
-ContainerRegistryUser <optional> -ContainerRegistryPassword <optional>

Notice that the New-AzAppServicePlan has the -HyperV flag which indicates to create the ASP in a special machines that support Hyper-V nested virtualization which is required to power the Windows Containers.
If your container is a Linux containers, just replace the -HyperV flag for -Linux and this will indicate the ASP must be provisioned with Linux machines to power your Linux container.
For more information, refer the below Microsoft sites:
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azappserviceplan?view=azps-12.3.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebapp?view=azps-12.3.0
If you use CLI, this is similar:
For Windows Containers:
az appservice plan create --resource-group rg --location region --name asp --hyper-v 
--sku P1v3

For Linux Containers:
az appservice plan create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyPlan --is-linux --sku S1

